How asynchrony works in Spring Framework?
How to asynchronously execute this method? I read on the Internet and it says that by default Spring is not asynchronous. But I noticed a strange feature: when testing this endpoint using Postman with 100 virtual threads, the test result shows that it processes 3.5 requests per second. But if I remove CompletableFuture and the @Async annotation, then the endpoint while testing processes 27 requests per second. But if Spring really wasn't asynchronous, then on my CPU with 12 threads, the maximum processing speed would be 6 requests per second (according to a delay of 2 seconds).
I'm not good at asynchrony in Spring, could you give me a code example when using asynchrony would be useful and how to simply configurate it?
endpoint:
@Async
@GetMapping("/async")
public CompletableFuture<String> testAsync() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return "Result of long operation";
    });
}

I also added @EnableAsync annotation and Executor method in Spring Boot Config class:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class TestBootApplication implements AsyncConfigurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }
}


I don't think your comparison would work correctly (without async you are just returning an object without any delay, but I don't want to start debugging your demo code so just to answer your question: lets say I want to allow user to trigger somewhat of a longer process like generating a monthly/yearly bill statement. In cases where generating such bill takes longer than a minute it is more practical to make it async and just return immediate reply the report will be sent to your email - please allow for up to 10 minutes for report to be generated

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync consumes built-in ForkJoinPool, if my memory serves me right, it's default capacity is #cores - 1, basically, you are misusing it: you should submit computational tasks only to the built-in ForkJoinPool, and in case of spring  you need to return CompletableFuture.completedFuture instead of submitting anything to any pool. When you are removing @Async and CompletableFuture.supplyAsync controller starts consuming tomcat's pool which has capacity of 200 threads. Using Thread.sleep you are actually comparing capacity of pools, not performance.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method and https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html

@EnableAsync won't change a thing. The CompletableFuture from the controller will be executed using the async capabilities of the Servlet API and for this it will use a TaskExecutor the default one has a very limited number of threads assigned. Adding the @Async makes it even worse as it will now be handled by the async support in the servlet api, it will also be executed as an async task by the regular async support and due to the supplyAsync it will use yet another thread (or place in the queue). So ditch the @Async, supplyAsync and just return using a completedFuture.
